# How to get the domain and string to the first slash

Tags: python, regex

For example like this

```
 url = https://example.com/test/myname/myname.jpg
 result = re.search('(?:https?://)?(?P<host>.*?)(?:[:#?/@]|$)', url)
```

I can get the `example.com` with this.

However I want to get the `example.com/test` (string before first `/`)

how can I do this?

Comment: You should consider using `urillib.parse` to parse URLs.  This specific example might work OK with `string.split`, but it's good practice to use a URL parser to parse URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `re` you can easily by splitting the list.

```py
url = 'https://example.com/test/myname/myname.jpg'
url = url.split('//')

result = url[1].split('/')[:2]

result = '/'.join(result)
print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
example.com/test
```

OR USING `re`

Bro, I am not good at the `re` module.

```py
import re
url = 'https://example.com/test/myname/myname.jpg'

result = re.search('(?:https?://)?(?P<host>.*?)(?:[:#?/@]|$).[^/]+', url)
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```py
<re.Match object; span=(0, 24), match='https://example.com/test'>
```

Comment: I hope you find something useful in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex pattern:

```
(?:\w*://)(?P<host>\w*\.\w*/\w*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wotbTN/1

```
import re

url = "https://example.com/test/myname/myname.jpg"
result = re.search('(?:\w*://)(?P<host>\w*\.\w*/\w*)', url)

print(result["host"])
```

Output:

```
example.com/test
```